# How come there is no literals for binary in dart

Tags: dart

In Dart there is a literal for hex but not for binary numbers?

```
  // bin
  print(0b00001); // Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 2 found. (Documentation)
  // Hex
  print(0x0001);
```

I know that I can use:

```
var number = int.parse("00001", radix: 2);
```

But why is there no literal?

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/581

Comment: Just got one more thumbs up :-)